# How do I apply meta programming to simplify my controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, metaprogramming

In my widgets_controller.rb I've got the following method

```
# GET /widgets/index_of_deleted
def index_of_deleted
  @widgets = Widget.order("name").deleted

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

And I've got many other models that will use this method. How can I create a module that has this method in a generic form, so that I can DRY up my controllers? I think the solution would be to call this..

```
index_of_deleted("widget")
```

..in my widgets_controller.rb. Or perhaps I can use the controller's name and just include this module in each controller that would use this method?

Specifically, what would the implementation of index_of_deleted look like within my Module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write modules and include them. Start by making a file in `lib`, maybe like so:

```
module WidgetExtras
  def index_of_deleted(widget)
    # implementation
  end
end
```

Then, in your `WidgetsController`, near the top, simple add:

```
include WidgetExtras
```

You might want to more explicitly namespace your modules (just nest them).

#### Edit

I'm not sure it's worth abstracting that really, how many models are there that need this functionality? You could write a helper instead to find deleted items:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def deleted_for_class( klass )
    klass.order('name').deleted
  end
end
```

But then why not just make a scope for 'deleted `Model` by name'...

#### Edit 2

You could write the implementation to set an instance variable...

```
def index_of_deleted( widget_name )
  klass = Kernel.const_get(widget_name.classify)
  instance_variable_set( "@#{widget_name.pluralize}", klass.order('name').deleted )
end
```

Comment: I'll clarify.. my question is actually about the #implementation part.  Passing a string into a method so that that string can become a instance variable name and a class name. Thanks. (fixed the post to clarify)

Comment: But, that said, I decided a better way to do this is to have logic within my one index method that depends on a param passed in via the URL. Not only will it simplify my controller, but it will also remove a whole bunch of unnecessary template files that I currently have to maintain.